# Getting the values from dataframe column, where the data are stored in a long nested lists

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, nested-lists, model.matrix

I am little bit new to python. I have loaded a `.mat` file into pandas DataFrame but there is one column `sensor` where the values are stored as a list of lists (nested list). Each list contains one time stamp and the reading at that time. All what I need is to get all the sensor readings alone in a new list without the time stamp. The attached photo is a simplified example to what I have.  [sensor_data_without_timestamp](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pbYpW.png).

As described in the photo, I have a `for loop` to iterate for each entry in `sensor` column and get the sensor reading to the new column `sensor_data_without_timestamp`. My data set is really big (630 rows and for each raw the length of the list is approx. 30.000) and this `for loop` alone takes about 10 minutes running.

**Isn't there any other method to get the sensor data more effectively ?**

Thanks in Advance :)

here is the code too:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'id':['1A', '2A', '3A'],
                   'sensor': [[[0,10], [2,15], [4,20]], [[0,7], [2,14], [4,18]], [[0,11], [2,16], [4,22]]]})

sensor_data_without_timestamp = []
for i in range(len(df)):
    l = []
    for a in range(len(df['sensor'][i])):
        l.append(df['sensor'][i][a][1])
    sensor_data_without_timestamp.append(l)

df['sensor_data_without_timestamp'] = sensor_data_without_timestamp
df.head()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can explode your dataframe then extract the second values and finally reshape your dataframe:

```
df['sensor_data_without_timestamp'] = \
    df['sensor'].explode().str[1].groupby(level=0).agg(list)
print(df)

# Output
   id                       sensor sensor_data_without_timestamp
0  1A  [[0, 10], [2, 15], [4, 20]]                  [10, 15, 20]
1  2A   [[0, 7], [2, 14], [4, 18]]                   [7, 14, 18]
2  3A  [[0, 11], [2, 16], [4, 22]]                  [11, 16, 22]
```

**Update**
If you have always a list of 3 elements:

```
df['sensor_data_without_timestamp'] = \
    np.vstack(df['sensor'])[:, 1].reshape(-1, 3).tolist()
print(df)

# Output
   id                       sensor sensor_data_without_timestamp
0  1A  [[0, 10], [2, 15], [4, 20]]                  [10, 15, 20]
1  2A   [[0, 7], [2, 14], [4, 18]]                   [7, 14, 18]
2  3A  [[0, 11], [2, 16], [4, 22]]                  [11, 16, 22]
```